# Is there a ReactiveCocoa method like publish, but that forwards the latest value to new subscribers?

Tags: reactive-cocoa

I often use ReactiveCocoa to track the latest value of some variable, like the text in a text field. Sometimes these latest values are actually themselves computed, in a way that multiple subscriptions causes the computations to happen multiple times. Often it would be *significantly* more efficient to merge these computations.

What I would like to use is `RACSignal* sharedComputationLatest = complicatedLatestValue.publish.autoconnect`, but then when new subscribers subscribe to the shared computation signal they are not told the latest value.

Is there a variant of `publish`, some sort of `publishLatest`, that already exists and does what I need? If not, does it already exist and have a name in .Net's Rx?

*Update:* It turns out that `autoconnect` has slightly different semantics than I thought, namely that if the number of subscribers goes to zero and then back up there is no re-connection. I needed the re-connection bit, so I implemented my own method (in an answer below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want [`-replayLast`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/2a6caf4029e3116ef957a8e4efcabe39b27ec24e/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal%2BOperations.h#L465).

Comment: Could you explain what the lifetime of the underlying subscription is? I wrote a test to see if it EVER cleans up the underlying subject when replayLast's signal is dealloc'd, but it doesn't? I'm reviewing the source and it seems like it... just lives forever? Is it actually never disposing it?? That's totally unacceptable for my use case.

Comment: In that case, you can use `-multicast:` to a `RACReplaySubject` (with capacity 1) and then `-autoconnect` on that. This isn't the default behavior because disposal is pretty confusing in the presence of multicasting, and not usually what consumers want.

Comment: It should still dispose when the replay subject is dealloc'd though, right? I submitted a bug to ReactiveCocoa about it. With that fixed this method would achieve what I need, so I'll leave it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a custom implementation (note: not thread safe):

```objc
-(RACSignal*) publishLatestAutoreconnect {
    __block int32_t subscriberCount = 0;
    __block RACDisposable* subscription = nil;
    __block RACReplaySubject* publishSubject = nil;

    return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable*(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        __block RACDisposable* _subscriberDisposable = nil;

        // auto[re]connect if we had no subscribers
        subscriberCount++;
        if (subscriberCount == 1) {
            publishSubject = [RACReplaySubject replaySubjectWithCapacity:1];
            subscription = [self subscribe:publishSubject];
        }

        // forward to subscriber
        _subscriberDisposable = [publishSubject subscribe:subscriber];

        return [RACDisposable disposableWithBlock:^{
            // stop forwarding to subscriber
            [_subscriberDisposable dispose];

            // disconnect if we now have no subscribers
            subscriberCount--;
            if (subscriberCount == 0) {
                [subscription dispose];
                subscription = nil;
                publishSubject = nil;
            }
        }];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Note that you could instead just do:

 [[signal multicast:[RACReplaySubject replaySubjectWithCapacity:1]] autoconnect];

Comment: @joshaber I just realized the semantics of autoconnect aren't what I thought they were. I want *dispose on zero* and *resubscribe on not zero*, but autoconnect only subscribes the first time things are non-zero. I'll rename the method to say autoreconnect. Finding this out was incredibly useful, so even though your suggestion won't work it was ultimately very helpful.